RDP W10 -> W11: Internal Error has occured, W11 -> W11 , Ubuntu Remmina -> W11
I have a weird situation where I have 2 different Windows 10 machines that won't be able to connect to a specific Windows 11 Machine, it gives 'Internal error has occurred'.
Situation:
Office:
W11 NUC
W11 PC
W10 LAPTOP

Home:
W10 PC

Datacenter:
Ubuntu Server

Target is W11 NUC @ Office.
W11 PC -> W11 NUC 
W10 LAPTOP -> W11 NUC  (both over 4G via Wireguard VPN, as locally with direct ip)
W10 LAPTOP -> W11 PC 
W10 PC -> W11 PC 
W10 PC -> W11 NUC 
Ubuntu Server -> W11 NUC 

When I started, even the W11 PC -> W11 NUC wouldn't work, so I followed this troubleshoot, and after that it worked according to the situation above: https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/troubleshoot/azure/virtual-machines/windows/troubleshoot-rdp-internal-error
Any ideas what else I can try?
Also tried HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\CredSSP\Parameters = 2
And
Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Credentials Delegation.
Double-click on “Allow delegating saved credentials with NTLM-only server authentication.”
Select “Enabled” and click “Show.”
Add TERMSRV/* to the list.

